# Why does the amplitude of a pendulum increases when continuously changing the rope length?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

The simplistic answer is that I'm pumping energy into the system thus the velocity increases and so is the amplitude.
I'm more interested in understanding it from forces considerations.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question, but I hope nobody answers in full, because this is exactly the sort of problem where you will learn the most by thinking it through in detail for yourself.

Your first thought, that by pulling the rope you are doing work, and therefore providing energy, is correct.

Your next thought, that one should try to see what is going on in terms of forces and momentum, not just energy, is also good thinking. I will provide just the following general pointers.

First, simplify the problem down to its essentials: so suppose the rope is light and the mass on the end of it can be considered simple, rigid and of negligible diameter. Now remind yourself of Newton's second law which says this mass will accelerate in the direction of the sum of the applied forces. Think carefully about the direction of motion of the mass just before the rope is shortened a bit, and then the direction of motion after the rope has moved. Is it true that the force from the rope is always at right angles to the velocity? If in doubt, treat the case where the mass is moving slowly and the rope has been shortened or jerked upward rapidly.

Good luck!

Comment: I like this response.  I went through this process myself years ago, and it was very enlightening.   There are lessons here that go beyond problem solving.  I've carried those lessons with me ever since.